# Flutter Initialization failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-run

Flutter failed to initialized while I was run it. First, it gave me an error of java uses or overrides depreciated API. Recompile with xlint. deprecation for details.Happened after adding firebase core and firebase auth [Flutter initialization failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nq1D.png) Then I run the flutter command now I got the error below

please help

Comment: Try updating Flutter by running `flutter upgrade`.